# How is the program using recursion and for loop what is the need for tail as a function argument in the below program?

Tags: python

Consider the following code: How is the program using recursion and for loop what is the need for tail as a function argument in the below program?

```
def permutations(head, tail=''):
    if len(head) == 0: 
        print(tail)
    else:
        for i in range(len(head)):
             permutations(head[0:i] + head[i+1:],tail+head[i])

permutations('abcd')
```

Comment: Hi there. You seem to have a number of questions. Could you ask each question separately?

Answer (score 0):

This function is used to get all the possible permutations of the characters of a `str`.

The recursion part is responsible for taking characters from `head` and puting them in `tail`, and when `head == ''` its prints the `tail`.

The role of `for` loop is to consider all the possibilities. Indeed, it start by taking the first character from `head`, then the second, then the third, and so on.

By combining these two parts, we get all the permutations.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you! I still cant visualize the control flow when permutation() is called again inside the function as recursion